# Can't get lambda's to compile in Netbeans 7.1.1+JDK8 (jdk-8-ea-bin-b35)

Tags: netbeans-7, java-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lambda expressions don't work in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176936/lambda-expressions-dont-work-in-java-8)

Simple, pointless app with a lambda:

> public static void main(String[] args) {
>           FileFilter java = (File f) -> f.getName().endsWith(".java");
>       }

Set it to use JDK 8. Compile/Runs fine if I don' try to use a lambda.

However if I do I get:

> Compiling 1 source file to ...\JavaApplication1\build\classes
>   ...JavaApplication1\src\javaapplication1\JavaApplication1.java:20:
>   error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.8
>           FileFilter java = (File f) -> f.getName().endsWith(".java");   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions) 1 error

Seems to be confused over whether it should be source 8 or source 1.8

---

Works now when using the lambda specific version, e.g. below runs fine:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.asList(new File("c:/").listFiles((File f) -> f.getName().endsWith(".txt")))
        .forEach( file-> {System.out.println(file);});
    }
}
```

Comment: Why was this closed? The duplicate pointed to came after mine, not before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get lambda expressions to compile, you will need to download the version of jdk from http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/. You will also get red squiggles on lines that contain lambda expression, but it will compile and run just fine, so just ignore them :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem exactly

Answer (score 2):

[Download the lambda binary](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) and then replace your old jdk8 with this new one, which has support for binary.

Then it should work.