# Lambda expressions don't work in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, javafx-2, java-8

I have a virtual machine running Windows XP SP3 32-bit. On this machine
I installed the Java SE JDK 8 build b44 Developer Preview from [here](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

I also installed the JavaFX 2.1 SDK.

It works fine:

```
java -version
> java version "1.8.0-ea"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b44)
> Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b14, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I tried running the following program (taken from [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2012/05/using-lambda-expressions-of-java-8-in-java-fx-event-handlers/)):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBase;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButtonBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LambdasWithJavaFx extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton("Click");
        final StringProperty btnText = button.textProperty();

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {
                ToggleButton source = (ToggleButton) actionEvent.getSource();
                if (source.isSelected())
                {
                    btnText.set("Clicked!");
                }
                else
                {
                    btnText.set("Click!");
                }
            }
        });

        root.setCenter(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(200);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The program compiled and ran as expected.

I followed the instructions in that article and replaced the button event-handling code with this:

```
button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->
{
    ToggleButton source = (ToggleButton) event.getSource();
    if (source.isSelected())
    {
        btnText.set("Clicked!");
    }
    else
    {
        btnText.set("Click!");
    }
});
```

When compiling, I get the following error (on the line `button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event)->`):

```
> lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.8
> (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

I added the argument `-source 8`, nothing changed.

All I wanted was to check the lambda expressions functionality in Java 8. Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: Maybe the implementation isn't complete yet.  Have you checked the release notes?  Do they say that Lambdas should be working?  Anyway, this is something you should probably be discussing with the Java developers ... using the feedback channels provided (whatever they are).

Comment: @StephenC Well, this version of JDK/JRE 8 is the latest I could find (release date: 21 June 2012). And it took me 20 seconds to find that code sample, which means there are a lot more out there. I assume they should work, maybe not perfectly but... why keep releasing Developer Preview versions if the most important feature is non-existent ?

Comment: The compiler complained that you have `-source 1.8` in the arguments. Did you edit that argument, or literally "add the argument `-source 8`"? Could it be that you don't have full control over the `javac` command line so that the invalid argument is still there?

Comment: @SoboLAN Because their goal with pre-releases is to iterate over the JDK, not one specific language feature.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It gives out the same error, regardless if I'm specifying the `-source 8` argument or not.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand what you're saying. What do you mean "iterate over the JDK" ?

Comment: @SoboLAN JDK releases aren't for a specific language feature, it's the entire JDK. They'll continue to drop releases with what's currently available whether or not it's complete.

Comment: What I want to say is that if you *don't* specify the `-source 8` argument and the compiler complains about seeing `-source 1.8`, that is suspicious to me. It is as if the argument `-source 1.8` somehow ended up on the command line. The Java version 1.8 never even existed (assuming that they now use 8 as the version). Then again, that might just be a bug in the preview version itself.

Comment: There are also regular builds of the [Lambda JDK Project](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to download the binaries which contain the Lambda expressions feature. Try downloading from here http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/. 
I remember reading in the mailing list that the lambda expression branch is being merged in the main JDK8 build, but not sure if its been done. But I use the build from the Lambda project page.

Comment: It worked, thank you. The way these releases are structured is a bit odd... Why release a JDK 8 with lambdas and one without ? Extra work for nothing IMO.

Comment: its mostly so that multiple projects are developed in parallel and then once these are stable, they get merged into the main JDK line. Yes its extra work, but imagine all the projects merging their code on to the main line? It would be only chaos and difficult for the project lead and others to manage the changes.

Comment: Any idea how to get this working on OS X? I have been trying to use the JDK8 lambda branch though it was not easy to get going. The main JDK8 branch has an OS X bundle, while the lambda version is just a `tar.gz` which I tried fiddling with but it kept breaking. It also wasn't the most pleasant thing to install.

Comment: @BrettRyan: could you be more specific about your problem? It should be straightforward in principle, as unpacking that tar.gz gives a complete JDK that you should just be able to point your IDE at.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/ releases, there are also JDK8 and JRE8 snapshot releases available in dmg, exe installer and tar.gz form from http://jdk8.java.net/download.html.

These jdk8 developer snapshots also now include lambda (and javafx8) functionality.  As of this writing, both lambda and javafx for jdk8 are still in feature and bug fix development mode.

I have found the http://jdk8.java.net/download.html weekly builds useful and useable for development (programs using them will occasionally crash on my mac, so it's definitely not something you would want to deploy to production even if the oracle license for the builds permitted that, which they don't).

If you want the absolute latest bleeding edge or customized jdk builds, you can build your own using [obuildfactory](https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki).  Such builds use an OpenJDK licensing model rather than an Oracle JDK licensing model, which may be preferable for some development projects, though, personally, I stick with Oracle JDK builds when I can.